# Multi-Environment S3 Asset Paths

Tags: multi-environment, s3

If I have three environments; local, dev, and live, and want assets to be setup like this:

local: stored in a local directory (/public/uploads)
dev: stored on S3 dev bucket
live: stored on S3 live bucket

What's the best way to set this in a multi-environment config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't currently possible.

[This feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/836) is very similar to what you're requesting... however, it would still require that all of your environments use the same *type* of asset source.

Answer (score 2):

We created a plugin to help solve this problem:
https://github.com/Firstborn/Craft-CMS-Environment-Settings

This plugin allows you to specify different configurations per environment on a single asset source.